# How can i insert value in timestamp datatype column in SQL using java or JSP

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jsp

I have tried to add value using preparedStatement.
----Some piece of Code----
    `

```
String query = "INSERT INTO COMMENTS VALUES(?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setString(1, email);
            ps.setString(2, name);
            ps.setTimestamp(3, now);
```

3rd column is timestamp type. But this is showing error.
It shows a whole list of packages needed to be imported. But when i import a package, it asks me to create a variable named 'now'.
Help me, how to fill timestamp field in database using java or JSP.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Create and [`Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) and set it. What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

'now' needs to be of type java.sql.Timestamp

you can run a quick test by doing

```
ps.setTimestamp(3,getCurrentTimeStamp());
```

where getCurrentTimeStamp() is

```
public java.sql.Timestamp getCurrentTimeStamp() {
        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        return new java.sql.Timestamp(today.getTime());
    }
```

Comment: Or even  

public java.sql.Timestamp getCurrentTimeStamp() {
        return new java.sql.Timestamp(java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

Answer (score 0):

To shorten HocusPocus correct answer even more, maybe

```
ps.setTimestamp(3, new java.sql.Timestamp(java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()));
```